# Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/test"

Tags: angularjs, protractor

My e2e tests run fine if I run them againts my local dev system. If I run them against our production system I always get the following error for each test case right after I do a `browser.refresh()`:

```
Message:
  Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/test"
Stack:
  Error: Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/test"
  at ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:102:16
  at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20)
  at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
  at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (...\ich\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:563:12)
```

Sometimes protractor even fails to load the page after login. The whole page synchronisation in protractor seems to be very unreliable.

The only 'special' thing on my page is that I manually bootstrap angular on a div element which I specified in my protractor conf as root element. As I said the tests run fine against my local machine.

--- EDIT ---

I think it is also worth mentioning that my baseUrl points to our www subdomain where the login happens. After the login the client gets redirected to a different subdomain. The redirects are handled in js. I recently changed `browser.refresh()` to `browser.driver.navigate().refresh()` which now loads the current url but that didn't fix the problem. It seems to me that protractor has some problems with page synchronisation on reloads.

Comment: did you disable debug info in production mode ? compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false) ?

Comment: no, I didn't do that

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, protractor seems to have lots of issues with refreshing the page when you need to manually bootstrap an app. Kind of annoying that this framework is so fragile.